# Is there a listing of all the changes to A Canticle for Leibowitz between the magazine and novel versions?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, adaptation-comparison, a-canticle-for-leibowitz

The original magazine novelettes that became *A Canticle for Leibowitz* were apparently heavily reworked for the final novel publication, after Miller's conception of the work as a whole changed.

> Only after I had written the first two and was working on the third did it dawn on me that this isn't three novelettes, it's a novel.  And I converted it.

I have seen scattered mentions of some specific changes, such as changes to the names of some characters to make them more thematic.  However, what I have not located is a complete listing of all the revisions that were made.  Has such a thing been created?

Ideally, this would be something along the lines of Douglas A. Anderson's discussion of the revisions made to *The Hobbit* in his [annotated version](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_Annotated_Hobbit) of the book, which includes the full textual history of the published versions, along with notes.  [This Web page](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/10/12/study-guide-for-walter-m-miller-jr-a-canticle-for-leibowitz-1959/), by Washington State professor Paul Brians, has excellent notes for helping to understand *A Canticle for Leibowitz*, but it apparently only covers the novel version.

Comment: Great question. I was wondering same thing. And I’m fact when this “beta-testing” of works from serialized “advance” publishing that was quite the rage of the genre from 40s through 60s stopped being the norm.