# Is the original, incomplete manuscript of Saint Leibowitz and the Wild Horse Woman available anywhere?

Tags: a-canticle-for-leibowitz

In a similar vein to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258874/is-there-a-listing-of-all-the-changes-to-a-canticle-for-leibowitz-between-the-ma) I asked yesterday, I am wondering about what had to be done to complete Walter M. Miller, Jr.'s second novel *[Saint Leibowitz and the Wild Horse Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Leibowitz_and_the_Wild_Horse_Woman)*.

The book is an interquel, set shortly after "*Fiat Lux*," the second part of *A Canticle for Leibowitz*, in an approximately Renaissance milieu.  Miller had been working on it, slowly, for at least two decades, and it seems to portray a much more ambivalent and cynical view of the Catholic Church than the author had apparently held when he was younger.  It addresses the political problems and entanglements of the New Roman papacy, analogous to the real-world "Babylonian" captivity of the French-controlled popes in Avignon and the worldliness of the subsequent Italian popes during the Renaissance and the Italian Wars.  (E. R. Chamberlin's classic history, *The Bad Popes*, covers much of this material.)  Miller never finished *Saint Leibowitz and the Wild Horse Woman*; he took his own life—something that many observers related to his dissatisfaction with Catholicism—in 1996.

According to *Walter M. Miller, Jr.:  A Reference Guide to His Fiction and His Life*, by William H. Roberson, Miller had designated [Terry Bisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Bisson) (author of "Bears Discover Fire" and "They're Made Out of Meat") to complete the book, and approximately the last hundred pages of the published novel were written by Bisson.  However, I would like to know more about how much of the story was Miller's work.  Did he have the ending sketched out in some level of detail?  Ideally, this would mean getting to see Miller's original manuscript and whatever notes accompanied it.  However, if that is not possible (and it probably isn't), is there any more detailed information available about how much Bisson had to do to finish the book—what kinds of edits he made to the earlier parts; how he decided what themes to emphasize in the parts he wrote; etc.?

Comment: It rather looks like his family have held onto his papers (which presumably includes his manuscript) rather than lodging them with a university or public archive

Answer (score 7):

[According to Bisson](https://archive.ph/20130222101113/http://www.sff.net/people/TBisson/miller.html#selection-187.1-199.24), the back portion of the book was basically absent and what was written to finish it was largely based on Miller's letters to his editor and publisher explaining what he was *planning* to write (e.g. to prove to them that his book was still in progress and that he didn't need to return his advance).

In total there appear to be a couple of pages that were written by Miller out of the last hundred or so. Bisson was careful to incorporate pretty much everything that he was able to get his hands on.

> Miller had left a fairly detailed outline showing where he wanted the
> book to go. Some of it was in the form of letters to Congdon; some was
> notes to Aronica and himself, including several scenes complete with
> dialogue. I wrote the last hundred-odd pages of the book according to
> Miller's instructions. I used every word of his dialogue and
> description, and even worked in scraps from Canticle for continuity.
> Miller was big on repeated images: buzzards, mules, and one old
> Wandering Jew.

Much to his surprise, the manuscript itself (e.g. that was handed over to Bisson) was the first 600-ish pages of the book and survived pretty much as written by Miller.

> Congdon gave me a box that weighed more than a small dog. I hauled it
> home before opening it. The manuscript inside was almost 600 pages
> long! I have been a writer long enough to know what it means to get
> stuck on a book. You meander, you fiddle, you rewrite--whatever.
> Miller had described his state to Congdon as like "trying to spit
> through a screen." So I was expecting, as I said, a mess.
>
> I read all that afternoon and most of that night. I finished the book
> at ten the next morning. It was brilliant. It was beautiful. It was
> almost perfect. There wasn't a line or a word out of place. This was
> no rough draft or heap of fragments, but a seamless, exotic and
> incredibly rich masterpiece that motored along confidently, elegantly
> and masterfully for 592 pages--
>
> And then stopped short.